# Почему внутри элемента с inline-block появляются отступы?

Tags: css

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении масштаба браузера колонки выстраивались по вертикали, вследствие чего появилась следующая проблема - при увеличении масштаба браузера внутри "block" блок с текстом "blocktext" начинает отделяться будто между ними существует отступ, тоже самое не понимаю откуда берется отступ между блоками inline по горизонтали. Конечно, по горизонтали можно воспользоваться отрицательным maring-left, но с вертикальным такое не пройдет, если увеличение масштаба больше 150%. И кстати, что можете посоветовать, чтобы рисунки внутри блока не заходили за область полукруга? При масштабировании тоже все наперекосяк.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjYij.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5mxx.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.list-menu {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.list-menu a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #ff9933;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list-menu a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .subdropdown {
  display: block;
}

.subdropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subdropdown a {
  display: block;
}

#navigation {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;
  background-color: #ff9933;
}

#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.blockpad {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
}

.bgimage {
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIchE.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.blocktext {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  background: #249FD6;
}

#footer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
  background: #ff9933;
  height: 60px;
}

.footer-info {
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.imgb {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="ru-RU">

<head>
  <title>Греция</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="j.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div class="header-icon">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
    <div class="list-menu">
      <a href="http://test1.ru">Главная</a>

      <div class="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <a href="#">Грец. товары</a>
        <div class="subdropdown">
          <a href="#">Для охоты и рыбалки</a>
          <a href="#">Стрельба по носорогам</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#">О нас</a>
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div class="blockpad">

      <div class="block">
        <div class="bgimage">
          <img class="imgb" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/65sUM.png" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap1"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="blocktext">
          <p> Some text block 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="bgimage">
          <img class="imgb" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Niv7.png" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap2"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="blocktext">
          <p> Some text block 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="bgimage">
          <img class="imgb" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icEqf.png" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap3"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="blocktext">
          <p> Some text block 3</p>
          <p> Some text next line</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-info"> Foot place</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<map name="planetmap1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="39,32, 40" alt="Иван" href="#">
</map>

<map name="planetmap2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0, 90, 90" alt="Иван" href="#">
</map>

<map name="planetmap3">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0, 80, 90" alt="Иван" href="#">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это инлайн отступы. Решения:

**Вариант 1**

В разметке убираем переносы для кнопок.

```
<main>
  <button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

**Вариант 2**

На родителя ставим font-size: 0; а уже к button задаем нужный размер шрифта.

```
main {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Вариант 3**

Можно закомментировать конец и начало строки.

```
<main><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
--></main>
```

Comment: По горизонтали отступ пропал, а вот по вертикали до сих пор остался. Сработал только 2 вариант.

Comment: Внутри block я использую еще два блока по 200px в высоту каждый, но картинка (360х200) не занимает всю площадь.

Comment: Кстати со 2 вариантом перестает работать перенос блока при увеличении масштаба.

Comment: Зачем же отвечаете, если сами пометили как дубликат?